# arraylist inorder traversal in java

Tags: java, arraylist, traversal, inorder

There is an arraylist of some class with values as

```
Node,Depth,Value
root,0,-2147483647
d3,1,4
e3,2,0
c5,2,0
c3,2,-3
c4,1,4
e3,2,0
c5,2,0
c3,2,-3
e6,1,4
d6,2,0
f4,2,0
f6,2,-3
f5,1,4
d6,2,0
f4,2,0
f6,2,-3
```

The object is such that it has the parent nodeid stored (ie for node d3 ,Parent(d3)-root. The relation is such that all the nodes below a given node `X` with `depth=X.depth+1` are its children. 
So, Root children are : `d3,c4,f5,e6`
 d3 children are : `c3`,`e3`,`c5`

Now, I have to write some code to generate the inorder traversal for it.
something like :

```
root,0,-2147483647
d3,1,4
e3,2,0
d3,1,4
c5,2,0
d3,1,4
c3,2,-3
d3,1,4
root,0,-2147483647
c4,1,4
e3,2,0
c4,1,4
c5,2,0
c4,1,4
c3,2,-3
c4,1,4
root,0,-2147483647
e6,1,4
d6,2,0
e6,1,4
f4,2,0
e6,1,4
f6,2,-3
e6,1,4
root,0,-2147483647
f5,1,4
d6,2,0
f5,1,4
f4,2,0
f5,1,4
f6,2,-3
f5,1,4
root,0,-2147483647
```

I have written a java method like this

```
private static void inordertraversal() {

ListIterator <nextmove> iter = nmstack.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    nextmove node=iter.next();
    if(node.depth==CutoffDepth)
    {
        maxdepth=true;
    }

    if (!maxdepth)
    {
        System.out.println(node.To.Name+","+node.depth+","+node.weight);

    }
    else
    {
        nextmove parent=findparent(node.parent);
        if (node.parent!=0)
        {   
        System.out.println(node.To.Name+","+node.depth+","+node.weight);
        System.out.println(parent.To.Name+","+parent.depth+","+parent.weight);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(parent.To.Name+","+parent.depth+","+parent.weight);
            System.out.println(node.To.Name+","+node.depth+","+node.weight);

        }
    }

}
}
```

But this is not GENERIC(if the depth is increased/changed it will not work) and incomplete as well. How do do this inorder traversal from the arraylist I have. Assume that the Arraylist has Node name,its depth and its parent's serial number. Could someone give me a pointer?
This is not a binary tree.

Comment: I fail to see the logic behind the result you want... Anyway, if you use Guava you may want to have a look at (and implement) [`TreeTraverser`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you absolutely want to take the `ArrayList` and construct a tree from it first. You really don't want to try an inorder traversal of the data structure while it's still represented as an `ArrayList`. That's your first task.

Once you've done that, an inorder traversal is pretty easy. It has this scheme:

1. recursively explore the left child;
2. process this node;
3. recursively explore the right child.

You have one major problem, though, which is that you say **this is not a binary tree**. Inorder traversal is **only defined for binary trees**, because you have to do the left-hand thing first, then the current node, then the right-hand path. That is not well defined for any other type of tree.